# VBA - (Excel) Why can't I set Textbox type for Userform without getting a type mismatch error?

Tags: vba, textbox, userform

I have a Userform and this is the code for my control button. Trying to pass a Textbox to a function using the following code

```
Private Sub pdclear_Click()
Dim textinput As TextBox
Set textinput = frmBigInputBox
Call clear(textinput)
End Sub
```

The line highlighted yellow in debug mode is

```
Set textinput = frmBigInputBox
```

Why does this cause a "13 type mismatch" error??? What am I doing wrongly?

Comment: You can't assign a `Form` object to a `TextBox` variable. Maybe you mean: `Set textinput = frmBigInputBox.SomeTextBox`?

Comment: please elaborate. How and where am I doing that? Can you show me how to make this work? @Bond

Comment: On the line that you're getting the error. Isn't `frmBigInputBox` a `UserForm` object?

Comment: frmBigInputBox is the name of my Textbox

Comment: Why did you prefix it with `frm`?

Comment: I don't know.. *sigh* I suck at naming things

Comment: I don't think it's a textbox or you wouldn't be getting an error there.

Comment: well when I run Debug.Print TypeName(NoteEntryForm1.frmBigInputBox)  it comes back TextBox Thus I'm pretty sure it's a textbox and is why I am confused about the error I am getting above.

Comment: Maybe you should use `Set textinput = NoteEntryForm1.frmBigInputBox` then?

Comment: yup just tried it and it still comes back run-time error 13 Type Mis Match

Comment: Do a check with `Typeof frmBigInputBox is Textbox`, please

Comment: This is I know it's a textbox. I named it myself I can see it in the properties window. It's there. I can type in it and I can pull values from it. Also If I don't use a function and just use a sub and call the objects specifically I can get this working just fine. So why am I getting the type mismatch?

Comment: Debug.Print (TypeOf NoteEntryForm1.frmBigInputBox Is TextBox)
Debug.Print TypeName(NoteEntryForm1.frmBigInputBox) returns False and Textbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using MSForms.TextBox. As in

```
Dim textinput As MSForms.TextBox
```

Works for me.

Comment: oh gezz what the hell is that??? totally inconsistent from everything else in VBA. I would have NEVER figured that out on my own. It works Thanks guys!!! I love StackOverFlow

Answer (score 2):

I could reproduce the error and found this: http://forums.devx.com/showthread.php?168758-Excel-VBA-Using-TypeOf

So you will have to define it as `MSForms.TextBox`, it seems.

Comment: oh geezz what the hell is that? Totally inconsistent from everything else in VBA. It works now. Thanks guys, I would have never figured that out on my own. I love StackOverFlow